# Wildfly in domain mode not deploy my war file

Tags: docker, deployment, jboss, dockerfile, wildfly

Here is my Dockerfile, it won’t deploy in domain mode, after entering to wildfly web GUI, on deployment does not show my war file, but when I upload manually and deploy it work without any problem.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly  
ADD your-awesome-app.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/deployments/
```

`docker run -it jboss/wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/domain.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0`

Build and Run:

`docker build --tag=jboss/wildfly .`

Run it:

`docker run -it -p 9990:9990 -p 8080:8080 jboss/wildfly`

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment scanner does not work in domain mode. You'd have to deploy using CLI or some other means of management.